# Url is taking the right parameters but not displaying right result on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to filter based on categories and sub categories. Right now I am doing it without any ajax.

Following is my controller method

```
def filter 
    x = params[:category_id]
    y = params[:sub_category_id]
    #@wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.Approved.where(category_id: "#{x}", sub_category_id: "#{y}")

    if x
      @wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.Approved.where(category_id: "#{x}")
    elsif x && y
      @wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.Approved.where(category_id: "#{x}", sub_category_id: "#{y}")
    end
end
```

When I first filter based on categories, the url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/wanted_equipments/filter?utf8=%E2%9C%93&category_id=1
```

And displays the equipment under that category. 
Next when I select the subcategory and enter filter. The url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/wanted_equipments/filter?utf8=%E2%9C%93&category_id=1&sub_category_id=3
```

It is supposed to filter further based on sub_category_id. But it is displaying the same data as earlier i.e it is considering only category_id as the parameter even though the url takes sub_category_id.

I know I am doing something wrong.I tried different conditions but not able to solve this. Could somebody please tell me how should I change the controller in order for it to consider the subcategory as well ?

Comment: What is Approved here? I thinks its a scope & its name should be approved

Comment: Oh that is a function from admin side. It displays only approved equipments,

Comment: you should use the function name with lower case, apart from this, the below answers are good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with your if condition. try change to :

```
if x && y
  @wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.Approved.where(category_id: "#{x}", sub_category_id: "#{y}")
elsif x
  @wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.Approved.where(category_id: "#{x}")
end
```

Because your `if x` condition true then it not move to eslif block. hope this works.

Comment: This is working. But how can I make it fetch only category_id when I don't select any sub_category_id? for example this url: `http://localhost:3000/wanted_equipments/filter?utf8=%E2%9C%93&category_id=1&sub_category_id=` should display data under that category_id.

Comment: Check your condition with present? also like `if x.present? && y.present?` and in elsif `elsif x.present?` It will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is problem of sequence

In your code condition first check `x` is `present?` or not if `x` is present then it will not going to check second condition

So, change your code sequence as follow

```
if x && y
  @wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.Approved.where(category_id: "# {x}", sub_category_id: "#{y}")
elsif x
  @wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.Approved.where(category_id: "#{x}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     @wanted_equipments = if y
                           WantedEquipment.Approved.where(category_id: "#{x}", sub_category_id: "#{y}")
                          else
                           WantedEquipment.Approved.where(category_id: "#{x}")
                          end if x
```